# mongoid TTL option doesn't work

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ttl

```
class Event
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :status, type: Integer
    index({ status: 1 }, { expire_after_seconds: 3600 })
end
```

I knew TTL option for MongoDB and Mongoid.
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/commit/ac3c4bbe43c8756daff844c808c99b84f10834bc

But its ttl option doesn't work since I update and upgrade ruby gems and brew packages.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: now I use MongoDB 2.4.5.

Comment: In the server, the option is expireAfterSeconds and not expire_after_seconds — could that be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your :status field must be a date BSON type. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#constraints